# Retrieve text from a textbox in visual studio ( windows store app)

Tags: c#, express, textbox, windows-store-apps

In windows store app( express 2013 for windows), i have created a textbox. Now i want to capture or retrieve the text entered by the user for further operations ( specifically, assign the user text to a string).
I tried this :

```
string input = InputBox.Text;
```

in the event handler for textbox.But this doesn't seem to work.

Any help is welcome.

```
<TextBox Text="TextBox"
             x:Name="InputBox"
             Grid.Row="1"
             HorizontalAlignment="Right"
             VerticalAlignment="Center" 
             Width="402" 
             Height="48"
             FontFamily="Arial Black"
             FontSize="28"
             FontWeight="Bold"
             VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
             HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" Margin="0,77,0,84"
             TextAlignment="Left" TextChanged="InputBox_TextChanged"
             />
```

C# code follows :

```
private void InputBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        string input = InputBox.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Did you renamed your textBox1 or whatever into InputBox?

Comment: *doesn't seem to work* Can you elaborate ?

Comment: i guess by elaborate you mean the error : "The name 'InputBox' does not exist in current context."

Comment: Show all your code or at least that function where error occurs

Comment: Updated the question. Error is as mentioned in previous comment.it occurs in c# code.

Answer (score 2):

the problem here is that you´re creating the string inside the event, so it will be erased after the event finish.
what you can do is to create a string inside the form class, and set its value on the text box event.

```
private string input = string.Empty;

private void InputBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    input = InputBox.Text;
}
```

Comment: Nope. Neither of the solutions worked. To be clear, I am not working on windows form, but on windows store app using express 2013 for windows ( mentioned in question). One more thing, i tried to use a textblock( not text box, another element in my app) in the event handler for checkbox, and it was the same error. I feel that the elements are not visible to each other( they may be declared private). I am still in the beginning stage of learning so i cant figure out exactly.

Comment: Update : I managed to figure out at what point the error occurs------- I have a checkbox named 'OkButton'. I adopted the first solution, by @Marciano. But as soon as i create the event handler for checkbox, the squiggly appears. Before creating the event handler for checkbox and after adopting your sol, the app ran fine. I'll be happy to share screenshots and more code if someone can tell me how.

Answer (score 1):

Remove TextChanged="InputBox_TextChanged" from xaml and use InputBox.Text wherever you want to use text of your TextBox.
InputBox_TextChanged will fire on every symbol you type in your textbox, so it is not good idea to get text in text_changed.